# Display the custom controls only for the users based on condition in the Identity User in abp framework

Tags: c#, abp

I have created few custom controls in the Identity user form using the abp framework.
But I need to display the custom control only for few Identity users.

I tried writing a if condition in ConfigureExistingProperties before adding a custom control.

Thanks,
N.ShanthaKumar.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would give these users a role or permission so that only they could show the component.

I don't know your UI type. usually there is an helper functions for that.
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Authorization

for example for angular

```
<div *abpPermission="'AbpIdentity.Roles'">This content is only visible if the user has 'AbpIdentity.Roles'permission.</div>
```